# iTunes has stopped updating this podcast because you have not listened to any episodes recently

Tags: itunes

iTunes has stopped updating this podcast because you have not listened to any episodes recently ...

Has anyone found a workaround for this annoyance with iTunes for the PC? I listen to podcasts with rockbox, so podcasts are never updated in iTunes, and I have to manually tell iTunes to resume updating my many podcast subscriptions.
I've read this is in-built, but perhaps some clever readers of this post have come up with a way to fool iTunes (a script temporarily changing the system date, a hack to some iTunes control file or script, etc.).

Thx.